# Replacing missing data with the mean of a subgroup in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a table in which there is some missing data that I'd like to replace with the mean of the some other, related data, based on certain conditions. I have some toy data to show the problem below:

```
var1    var2    var3
123.1    2.1    113
166.5    2.1    113
200.3    2.1    112
 NA      2.1    113
 NA      2.1     NA 
212.1    3.3    112   
 ...     ...    ...
```

What I'd like to do is be able to to fill in the NA values for `var1` with the mean of `va1` in the case where they both have the same `var2` and `var3`.

ie, for the first NA in the `var1` column, this matches on both var2 and var3 with the 1st and 2nd entries, so this would get the value of (123.1 + 166.5) / 2 .

The second NA in the `var1` column is missing the `var3` information so would be given the mean of all the other `var1` values where `var2 = 2.1.`

I'm relatively new to R and I can't seem to get the conditional logic correct -  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> What I'd like to do is be able to to fill in the NA values for var1 with the mean of var2 in the case where they both have the same var3.

Hmm... I don't think that's what you want, but to do that:

```
means <- tapply(var2, var3, mean, na.rm=T)
var1[is.na(var1)] <- means[match(var3[is.na(var1)], sort(unique(var3)))]
```

Comment: Thank you very much - if you wouldn't mind I'd love to hear about why you don't think I should do that (or be pointed to some other reading). EDIT: actually I see what you mean, I meant the mean of var1, given that that they both match. Wow - I worded that horribly. I think I can figure it out from your answer though.

Comment: your example values give the following value for `var1`: `[1] 123.1 166.5 200.3   2.1    NA 212.1`. One of these things is not like the other :) (hint it's 2.1)

Answer (score 3):

You should do multiple imputation instead:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "var1    var2    var3
123.1    2.1    113
166.5    2.1    113
200.3    2.1    112
 NA      2.1    113
 NA      2.1     NA 
212.1    3.3    112 ", header = TRUE)

library(mice)
impDF <- mice(DF)
plot(impDF)
comDF <- complete(impDF, "long")

library(data.table)
setDT(comDF)
comDF[, setNames(c(lapply(.SD, mean), lapply(.SD, sd)), 
                 c(paste0("var", 1:3), paste0("SDvar", 1:3))), 
      by = .id, .SDcols = paste0("var", 1:3)]
#   .id   var1 var2  var3   SDvar1 SDvar2    SDvar3
#1:   1 123.10  2.1 113.0  0.00000      0 0.0000000
#2:   2 166.50  2.1 113.0  0.00000      0 0.0000000
#3:   3 200.30  2.1 112.0  0.00000      0 0.0000000
#4:   4 173.70  2.1 113.0 34.80718      0 0.0000000
#5:   5 174.14  2.1 112.2 46.84131      0 0.4472136
#6:   6 212.10  3.3 112.0  0.00000      0 0.0000000
```

Obviously this works better with more data and other imputation methods might yield better results. Study the documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much - I'll spend some time looking into this now.

Comment: There *are* a few caveats to using this method. In general, for some basic analytic purposes, it may make more sense to hotdeck or singly impute. At any rate, the user's question doesn't give enough detail to get into it.